# Group by in Subquery SAS

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, subquery

Hi I have a dataset look like this

```
Brand   Category
----------------------
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       1
B       1
C       1
A       2
C       2
C       2
C       2
```

and I want to get the market share for each brand in each category. Say, market share for A in category 1 is 3/6=50%.

I used the sql code

```
    proc sql;
    select
    Brand, 
    count(brand) / (select count(category) from dataset group by category) as percent
    from dataset
    group by brand, category;
```

but the SAS report the error of

```
 ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row.
```

Please help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why aren't you using PROC FREQ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. because it would create a problem for brand A which appears in category 1 and 2. I use sql because it is easier calculate the market concentration index which equals to (percentage of a) ^2 + (percentage of b) ^2 + (percentage of c) ^2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the category total counts back onto the brand*category combinations. PROC SQL will do that for you automatically if you want.

```
data have ;
  input Brand $ Category $ @@;
cards;
A 1 A 1 A 1 B 1 B 1 C 1 A 2 C 2 C 2 C 2
;

proc sql;
  select brand
       , category
       , nobs
       , sum(nobs) as cat_total
       , nobs/calculated cat_total as percent
   from (select category,brand,count(*) as nobs 
         from have 
         group by 1,2
        )
   group by category
   order by 1,2
 ;
```

NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(category) from dataset group by category
```

This subquery returns more than 1 row. It returns the count for each category. But you want the count of a specific category, so replace it with

```
select count(category) from dataset where category = d.category
```

and make sure you give `dataset` an alias i.e. `from dataset d`

Here's another way using derived tables where one derived table contains the count for each brand/category and the second table contains the total count per category.

```
select cnt/total, t1.brand, t1.category 
from (
    select count(*) cnt, brand , category
    from dataset 
    group by brand, category
) t1 join (
   select count(*) total, category
   from dataset 
   group category
) t2 on t2.category = t1.category
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use proc freq as Tom mentioned.

```
proc freq data = yourdata;
table brand*category/missprint list;
run;
```

That should give you the %'s you want without complicated sql programming.